# ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion crashes on iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook, ios10

I use below code to access contacts in my iOS application. It was working fine in iOS<10 but with Xcode 8 and iOS 10 it crashes:

```
- (void)btcContacts_tap {
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook =  ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (granted) {
            _addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

            [[_addressBookController navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

            _addressBookController.delegate = self;
            [_addressBookController setPredicateForEnablingPerson:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.@count > 0", ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty]];
            [_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
            [self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self showMessage:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"PLEASE_GRANT_CONTACTS", LIApplicationLanguage(), nil) andAdvertise:@"" andService:nil andTransactionState:kTTTransactionStateInfo];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have set `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` to a method for logging the crash report but even the exception handler is not calling...

Does someone else faced this problem too?

Comment: Husein it is deprecated from iOS 9.You can't use that.You should use Contact framework.

Comment: If you want to do the application with contacts framework I will help you.I will post answer using contacts framework.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

iOS 10:

You need to put the `NSContactsUsageDescription` in your plist. Like:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos</string>
```

See all usage descriptions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).

Comment: Really helped me.. Thank

Comment: An xcode error message indicating this would have been great. Thanks for solving this!

Answer (score 1):

Use `CNContactStore` , `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is depreciated.
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/addressbook/1622001-abaddressbookrequestaccesswithco?language=objc)